# Populate UIPicker with custom object field

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I have an object with an NSString property. I'd like to populate a UIPickerView with a mutable array of these objects, and use the string property as the title for each row. Any ideas on how to properly do this?

I tried to use the following code below, but the rows are left blank.

```
-(NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
return ((Vehicle*)[vehicleArray objectAtIndex:row]).vehicleType;
```

}

Comment: Is vehicleType an NSString? (And make sure you hook up your UIPickerView delegate properly)

Comment: Besides Enrico's question, what did you write in numbeOfComponentsInPickerView and numberOfRowsInComponent methods?

Comment: As in the earlier comment by @LordZsolt you need to have number of rows in component returning the actual number. In your case it needs to be `- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView { return [vehicleArray count]};

Comment: Yes, vehicleType is an NSString. Here's a pastebin to the relevant .m file http://pastebin.com/UFgyd0xM I made sure to double check that my connections are correct.